How to formalize statements in first/second-order logic, where the number of existential statements depends on a value?
I've been wondering about how to formalize statements in first/second-order logic, where there exist a number of objects with a certain property, but the number of existing objects depends on some other value.
A nice example of what I'm speaking of would be

(1) For all natural numbers $x > 1$, there are primes $p_1, ..., p_m$ such that $x = p_1 \cdot ... \cdot p_m$.

If we try to express (1) in some FOL formalization PA of Peano arithmetic (such as this), a naive attempt would be something along the lines of
$$\forall x > 1 \exists p_1...\exists p_m(Prime(p_1) \land ... \land Prime(p_m) \land x = p_1 \cdot ... \cdot p_m)$$
though that wouldn't be a valid formula, since the length of $\exists p_1...\exists p_m(...)$ isn't fixed, it depends on $x$.
The only way I could think of was to cheat, and express it as a meta-theorem about PA, so something like

For all $x > 1$, a formula $\exists p_1 ... \exists p_m(Prime(p_1) \land ... \land Prime(p_m) \land \overline{x} = p_1 \cdot ... \cdot p_m)$ is provable in PA for some $m > 0$.

where $\overline{x}$ is some representation of $x$ in PA.
How do you formalize statements like (1) in a first/second-order language?
Thanks for all help :]

Prove that $\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, and hence that $\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}^m$. Then you can quantify over a single number representing an $m$-tuple.

Would you accept a formalization in the language of set theory?

@Adayah Yes, sure .
The main question is how to express statements like (1) in some first/second order language in general, not specifically PA.

One way of representing arbitrary tuples as single numbers in Peano Arithmetic is Gödel's beta function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_%CE%B2_function:
$$\beta(a,b,c) = rem(a,1+(c+1)b)$$
(The remainder when $a$ is divided by $1+(c+1)b$).
Let's say we want to encode the sequence $x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ of natural numbers as a single natural number.
If $b$ is a large enough factorial, then $1+(i+1)b$ takes on relatively prime values for $i = 0,\ldots, n-1$. So by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we can pick an $a$ such that $$rem(a,1+(i+1)b) = x_i.$$
Note that this requires $1+(i+1)b > x_i$, but again we can do this by picking $b$ to be a suitably large factorial.
Thus, $a, b$, and the length of our sequence $n$ are enough to reconstruct our original sequence $x_0,\ldots, x_{n-1}$. And those entries are just going to be $\beta(a,b,i)$ for $i = 0, \ldots, n-1$. It's important to note that if you plug in a value of $i$ larger than $n$ into the beta function, it will give you junk data, so we need to keep track of the length $n$ of our list.
We can then encode $a, b$ and $n$ as a single number using some sort of pairing function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function, but I prefer to leave them separate and just have three quantifiers.
So what does this look like in practice? Let's say you want to express: $$\forall x \exists p_0...\exists p_{n-1}(Prime(p_0) \land ... \land Prime(p_{n-1}) \land x = p_0 \cdot ... \cdot p_{n-1})$$
We can translate "$\exists p_0 \ldots \exists p_{n-1}$" to "$\exists a, b, n$"
Then "$(Prime(p_0) \land ... \land Prime(p_{n-1}))$" becomes "$\forall i < n: Prime(\beta(a,b,i))$"
$x = p_0 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_{n-1}$ is a little tricky since it also has ellipses in it. We can create an intermediate translation that asserts that there is an intermediate sequence $y_0, \ldots, y_{n-1}$ with: $$y_0 = p_0, \qquad y_i = y_{i-1} \cdot p_i, \qquad y_n = x$$
$$\forall x: \exists p_0 \ldots \exists p_{n-1} (Prime(p_0) \ldots) \wedge \exists y_0, \ldots, y_{n-1} : y_0 = p_0 \wedge y_1 = y_0 \cdot p_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge y_{n-1} = y_{n-2} \cdot p_{n-1} \wedge y_{n-1} = x$$
So if we encode our $y_i$ as $\beta(c,d,i)$, we get the final translation:
$$\forall x: \exists a, b, n: \forall i < n: Prime(\beta(a,b,i)) \wedge \exists c, d: \beta(c,d,0) = \beta(a,b,0) \wedge \forall 0 < i < n: \beta(c,d,i) = \beta(c,d,i-1) \cdot \beta(a,b,i) \wedge \beta(c,d,i) = x$$


"How to formalize statements in first/second-order logic"

I am not sure this can be done in first-order PA, but in second-order logic one can just write $(\exists m\in\mathbb N)(\exists p\in\mathbb N^m)\; \big(x=p_1\cdots p_m)\big)$ where $p=(p_1,\ldots,p_m)$ (adding of course the primality condition).

The standard way to formalize this in first order set theory is to write:

For every $x \in \omega$ such that $x > 1$ there is $m \in \omega$ and a finite sequence $p : m \to \omega$ such that
(i) for all $i \in m$, $p(i)$ is a prime number, and
(ii) $x = \prod_{i < m} p(i)$.

This requires some work to formalize all the way down to the bare language of set theory, which contains just a single relation $\in$:

the constant symbol $\omega$ (the set of natural numbers in the von Neumann construction) must be replaced with a variable symbol together with its definition, i.e. $(\exists \omega) \big( \omega \text{ is the smallest inductive set} \land \ldots \big)$; of course "is the smallest inductive set" should be expanded as well;

$x>1$ could be replaced with $1 \in x$, where $1$ is again a variable introduced with $\exists$ and defined by $(\forall y) \big( y \in 1 \leftrightarrow y = \varnothing \big)$ (and $\varnothing$ was probably defined anyway in the previous item);

$p : m \to \omega$ should be replaced with the subformula
$$\begin{align*} &(\forall q \in p)(\exists i \in m)(\exists j \in \omega) \, q = (i, j) \\
\land & (\forall i \in m)(\exists j \in \omega) \, (i, j) \in p \\
\land & (\forall i \in m)(\forall j, j' \in \omega) \big( (i, j) \in p \land (i, j') \in p \rightarrow j = j' \big),\end{align*}$$
where the pair symbol $(i, j)$ should be further expanded using the Kuratowski pair definition;

$S$, $+$ and $\cdot$ should be defined inductively on $\omega$ in order to expand the part "$p(i)$ is a prime number";

(ii) can be written by saying that there is a sequence $q : m+1 \to \omega$ such that $q(0) = 1$, $q(S(i)) = q(i) \cdot p(i)$ for $i < m$ and $x = q(m)$.


